# Changed variable is not reflected in PGF chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a PGF bar chart where the values of the bars are given by variables, using `\newcounter`. Now, the counters are updated after the PGF plot is rendered. Therefore, the plot does not render correctly. How can I render the plot before the counters are updated, but making the PGF plot include the updated counters?

Example (not working)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcounter{criticalfindings}
\newcounter{highfindings}
\newcounter{mediumfindings}
\newcounter{lowfindings}
\newcounter{informationalfindings}

\setcounter{criticalfindings}{0}
\setcounter{highfindings}{0}
\setcounter{mediumfindings}{0}
\setcounter{lowfindings}{0}
\setcounter{informationalfindings}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Overzicht,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels={Kritiek, Hoog, Midden, Laag, Informatief},
        every axis plot/.append style={
            ybar,
            bar width=20,
            bar shift=0pt,
            fill
        },
        ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,\thecriticalfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,\thehighfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(3,\themediumfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(4,\thelowfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(5,\theinformationalfindings)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\stepcounter{informationalfindings}

\end{document}
```

Here, the `informationalfindings` counter has been incremented to 1. However, this is not reflected in the PGF plot. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you think that the graph is a kind of widget, like the ones that you can generate in `jupyter` notebooks, or in other software. But no, in LaTeX the graph is generated/plotted with the current value of the parameter, set "in stone" in the PDF file at that point.

I changed your code so that the graphic generation is inside a macro that you can call whenever you want to show the effect.

If you want a dynamic graph that tracks the change in counters, I fear LaTeX (which is a *typesetting* system, meant to produce a document, not a widget) is not the correct tool.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcounter{criticalfindings}
\newcounter{highfindings}
\newcounter{mediumfindings}
\newcounter{lowfindings}
\newcounter{informationalfindings}

\setcounter{criticalfindings}{0}
\setcounter{highfindings}{0}
\setcounter{mediumfindings}{0}
\setcounter{lowfindings}{0}
\setcounter{informationalfindings}{0}

\newcommand{\domygraph}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Overzicht,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels={Kritiek, Hoog, Midden, Laag, Informatief},
        every axis plot/.append style={
            ybar,
            bar width=20pt,% <<<<<< NOTICE!!!
            bar shift=0pt,
            fill
        },
        ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,\thecriticalfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,\thehighfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(3,\themediumfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(4,\thelowfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(5,\theinformationalfindings)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\stepcounter{informationalfindings}

\domygraph

\stepcounter{highfindings}

\domygraph

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also

1. added a `compat` version for pgfplots (you had a warning about it)
2. added a dimension value for the bar width (newer `pgfplot` will consider a plain `20` to be the same units of the x-axis).

You should also probably add a fixed vertical scale.

Answer (score 1):

With some changes I have this

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcounter{criticalfindings}
\newcounter{highfindings}
\newcounter{mediumfindings}
\newcounter{lowfindings}
\newcounter{informationalfindings}
% changed
\setcounter{criticalfindings}{20}
\setcounter{highfindings}{10}
\setcounter{mediumfindings}{20}
\setcounter{lowfindings}{15}
\setcounter{informationalfindings}{30}

\begin{document} % added

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Overzicht,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels={Kritiek, Hoog, Midden, Laag, Informatief},
        every axis plot/.append style={
            ybar,
            bar width=20,
            bar shift=0pt,
            fill
        },
        ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,\thecriticalfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(2,\thehighfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(3,\themediumfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(4,\thelowfindings)};
        \addplot coordinates {(5,\theinformationalfindings)};
        %\stepcounter{informationalfindings}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to increment the counters after the pgf plots has been defined, AND that the counter increments are reflected in the previously defined plot. That is not the case in this MWE.

Comment: @twit Where and how? Your question is a lot confusing. And the code proposed not working at all.